# How to initialise nested arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, types, nested

Forgive a stupid question but I am new to C# & OOP.

Can anyone help me prevent a “System.NullReferenceException:”?

I’m trying to do an assignment following instructions and using what we’ve learned to date (arrays, classes and constructors).

I’ve created an array of StudentSubjects classes and embedded this in an array of Student classes.

I want to print out details of each student’s subjects.

I can access the `StudentArray[0]` fields OK but can’t get to the `StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[0]` fields because "Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

I’ve spent 2 weeks looking for an answer but cannot find any examples of how to set

```
StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[0].SubjectName = "Algebra";
```

Any advice most appreciated.  My code is below ....

```
using System;

namespace Nested_Arrays
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Student[] StudentArray = new Student[1];

            Console.WriteLine($"Hello");
            StudentArray[0] = new Student();
            StudentArray[0].StudentName = "Peter";
            StudentArray[0].StudentLocation = "Australia";
            Console.WriteLine($"{StudentArray[0].StudentName,10} {StudentArray[0].StudentLocation,15}");

            StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[0].SubjectName = "Algebra";
            StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[0].StudentsResult = "Pass";
            Console.WriteLine($"{StudentArray[0].StudentName,10} {StudentArray[0].StudentLocation,15} {StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[0].SubjectName,15} {StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[0].StudentsResult,10}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Goodbye");
        }

        public class Student
        {
            public string StudentName;
            private string studentName
            { get { return studentName; } set { studentName = value; } }

            public string StudentLocation;
            private string studentLocation
            { get { return studentLocation; } set { studentLocation = value; } }

            public StudentSubjects[] StudentSubjectsArray;
            private StudentSubjects[] studentSubjectsArray
            { get { return studentSubjectsArray; } set { studentSubjectsArray = value; } }

            //Constructor
            public Student() { }
        }

        public class StudentSubjects
        {
            public string SubjectName;
            private string subjectName
            { get { return subjectName; } set { subjectName = value; } }

            public string StudentsResult;
            private string studentsResult
            { get { return studentsResult; } set { studentsResult = value; } }

            //Constructor
            public StudentSubjects() { }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks really weird. I would like to suggest to use `List` instead of arrays - it's more flexible and safety way to work with collections.

Comment: Hello MaKCbIMKo.  I can't use List because this is for an assignment and I have to do what the teachers says - he says use arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the following:

```
StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray = new StudentSubjects[1];
StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[0] = new StudentSubjects();
// and only then
StudentArray[0].StudentSubjectsArray[0].SubjectName = "Algebra";
```

Comment: No, the OP needs to assign an array to `StudentSubjectsArray` first.

Comment: @juharr - this answer does just that.  Are you missing something, or am I?

Comment: hey MaKCbIMKo - your suggestion solves my problem.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you need to create the arrays before you assign objects in the array, although you can do both at the same time.

For example, if you want to do it all in one line, this would work:

```
Student[] StudentArray = {
    new Student {
        StudentName = "Peter",
        StudentLocation = "Australia",
        StudentSubjectsArray = new[] {
            new StudentSubjects {
                SubjectName = "Algebra",
                StudentsResult = "Pass"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Gabriel, it certainly does work.  It looks like a useful shorthand.  After 2 weeks banging my head against the wall I would never have come up with anything like your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a good practice is to initialize arrays in the constructor. In this way you are sure it is not null when using the object.

So do something like:

```
//Constructor
public Student() {
    this.studentSubjectsArray = new StudentSubjects[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks kadoga I'll try that.